# by/on/from their legs/toes/feet

Tags: collocations

what is the right collocation?

Monkeys hang down the tree from/by/on their feet/legs/toes.

If more than one collocation is possible in this sentence please point it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Monkeys hang down **from** a tree **by/using** their feet/legs/toes.

I can't choose the last part because I have not seen monkeys hanging from trees recently. I imagine it is *legs*.

Comment: You said you haven't seen monkeys recently (funny by the way ) but seriously let's say monkeys use their feet and toes to hang down, can we say "hagn down with their feet or toes" Or no, when we say legs we already mean that?

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I find "hanging *with* their feet" to sound very strange.  Hanging *by* their feet sounds much more natural.

Comment: Legs would be like hanging with their knees wrapped around a branch. Feet or toes would be different but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @stangdon Agreed. *using* would also be OK. I edited my answer.